# Regex for this dataset

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset which has following format:

```
product/productId: B000179R3I
product/title: Austin Reed Dartmouth Jacket
product/price: unknown
review/userId: A3Q0VJTUO4EZ56
review/profileName: Jeanmarie Kabala "JP Kabala"
review/helpfulness: 7/7
review/score: 4.0
review/time: 1182816000
review/summary: Periwinkle Dartmouth Blazer
review/text: I own the Austin....[whatever]...
---and above repetitions----
```

I tried to apply regex to make all columns (`str_extract("\\s.*")`) but the first space is also included every time.

One way is to extract `[space]XXXXXXX` and then remove space.

But is there any better way to do that, in Python?

Comment: try `str_extract(r'(?<=\s).*')`

Comment: i think the above is an `R` regex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you could do like the below,

```
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
        print(line.split(' ',1)[1])


B000179R3I
Austin Reed Dartmouth Jacket
unknown
A3Q0VJTUO4EZ56
Jeanmarie Kabala "JP Kabala"
7/7
4.0
1182816000
Periwinkle Dartmouth Blazer
I own the Austin....[whatever]...
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> for line in s.split('\n'):
        print(re.search(r'(?<=\s).*', line).group())


B000179R3I
Austin Reed Dartmouth Jacket
unknown
A3Q0VJTUO4EZ56
Jeanmarie Kabala "JP Kabala"
7/7
4.0
1182816000
Periwinkle Dartmouth Blazer
I own the Austin....[whatever]...
```

**OR**

```
for line in re.findall(r' (.*)', s):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks.
But is there a way to extract only words after "space" till new line like ->

B000179R3I

Austin Reed Dartmouth Jacket

unknown

--and so on---

Comment: yep, the above doest the same. i think this `str_extract(r'(?<=\s).*')` would work for you.